# "I am Negan" lifted from the movie Spartacus?

Tags: the-walking-dead, spartacus

Was the concept of unity in the "We're all Negan" motif ripped off (or homaged) from the scene in Spartacus where every character stands up and states, "I am Spartacus!".

Comment: Probably not I'd suggest...certainly the line is in the comic where the Saviours are more of a cult. The Spartacus quote is about protecting Spartacus himself (although it doesn't work) whereas Negan doesn't need protecting. There might be something about collective responsibility though.

Comment: Oddly enough I didn't Google this first, but [now that I have](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22i'm+Negan%22+spartacus) it appears to be discussed on several sites.  However, I can't find anything directly mentioned by anyone involved with the production of The Walking Dead.  The Spartacus theme is even listed on TV Tropes, with a reference to Negan.